# Configuring SSL with Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx

Now this might be a very simple issue but I can't seem to figure out how get SSL to work with Nginx. I will list what I have done so far:

1. Used certbot to create a fullchain.pem and privkey.pem file
2. Added the following code to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/pubgstats.info`

   ```
   server {


     listen 80;
     server_name pubgstats.info www.pubgstats.info;
     location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
           root /srv/www/pubg-stats;
     }

     location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
     location /secure {
           auth_pam "Secure zone";
           auth_pam_service_name "nginx";
     }

   }

   server {
       listen 443;
       ssl on;
       ssl_certificate /srv/www/pubg-stats/certs/fullchain.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /srv/www/pubg-stats/certs/privkey.pem;
       server_name pubgstats.info www.pubgstats.info;
       location / {
               root /srv/www/pubg-stats/;
       }
   }
   ```

   From what I understand, the configuration listens on port 80 and upgrades a HTTP request to HTTPS. The code was mostly taken from this [article](https://www.codementor.io/@marcoscasagrande/installing-express-nginx-app-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-ssl-using-certbot-pdt44g5gs). I added the SSL part of the configuration as stated [here](https://www.thesslstore.com/knowledgebase/ssl-install/nginx-ssl-installation/). Now visiting the site over HTTP works. On HTTPS, the connection is reset. What am I missing in the configuration and what's the best way to configure SSL with Nginx in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you didn't add this to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, but the issue appears to be that you've declared multiple `server` blocks for the same server. In that case, nqinx will usually choose the first depending on different criteria.

With this configuration, nginx will use SSL by default. If that is not what you want, remove `default_server`. You don't need `ssl on` as that is now obsolete and replaced with the ssl parameter in the listen directive.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 default_server ssl;
  ssl_certificate /srv/www/pubg-stats/certs/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /srv/www/pubg-stats/certs/privkey.pem;
  server_name pubgstats.info www.pubgstats.info;
  location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
        root /srv/www/pubg-stats;
  }

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
  location /secure {
        auth_pam "Secure zone";
        auth_pam_service_name "nginx";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was actually missing a vital include that included the ssl options for certbot from `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ss-nginx.conf`. Following this article: https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/ here along with the setup you provided it finally worked.